# Negative conditions in testthat

Tags: r, testing, testthat

Is it possible to write negative conditions in test_that() or expect_XXX() calls? Specifically I'd like to test for a string which does not contain a substring, so something like:

```
expect_that("Apples, Oranges, Banana", !matches('Onion'))
```

or

```
expect_not_match("Apples, Oranges, Banana", 'Onion')
```

I'm aware that I can use expect_true() in combination with e.g. grep:

```
expect_true(length(grep("Onion", "Apples, Oranges, Banana")) == 0)
```

But that doesn't seem too readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `testthat::not` ?

```
expect_that("Apples, Oranges, Banana", not(matches('Onion')))​​​​​​
```